# CMake target_compile_features unordered_map

Tags: c++11, cmake

I'm trying to introduce using CMake to build my C++ project.  When I run make I get an error :

```
[ 11%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/game.dir/InputHandler.cpp.o
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/unordered_map:35:0,
...
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/c++0x_warning.h:32:2: error: #error This file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011 standard. This support must be enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options.
 #error This file requires compiler and library support...
```

I realise this is because CMake is not invoking C++11 when it needs to in order to enable the use of the unordered_map.  After googling I know I need to use target_compile_features() in my CMakeLists.txt.  But I can't find anywhere which gives me the syntax/arguments I need to use, there's just examples e.g. on the CMake page it gives :

```
add_library(mylib requires_constexpr.cpp)
target_compile_features(mylib PRIVATE cxx_constexpr)
```

But I don't need cxx_constexpr, I don't even know what that is.  I need unordered_map.

Can anyone tell me the syntax I need to use please, preferably giving me some sort of reference to valid values to pass into that function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`std::unordered_map` is part of the STL, it isn't a language keyword like `constexpr` or `override`, etc. CMake doesn't provide compile features for STL functionality (that would be an overwhelming task to implement!). In your case, you really just want to tell CMake that you need C++11. [This article](https://crascit.com/2015/03/28/enabling-cxx11-in-cmake/) provides all the details you should need on this topic, but to summarise it for this particular question, adding the following near the top of your `CMakeLists.txt` file should give you what you need:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)
```